# Anaconda FileNotFound error during pytest in vscode

Tags: python, postgresql, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am trying to run some pytests on vscode in a conda environment. The connection to my postgres db is handled by flask/flask-sqlalchemy and I have installed the add-ons for pytest (pytest-flask, pytest-postgresql), to use some fixtures.

When I'm now trying to **run** a test (or all of them), I get the following error message:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/robert/software/anaconda3/envs/python38/bin/pg_ctl'
```

Now, this is somewhat obvious because the conda env indeed does not have a pg_ctl module. It is rather the (system-wide) installation of postgres, that has it. I tried to modify `PATH`, including the path to the pg_ctl module via the `.profile` config file, but:
!! once I execute the run command in vscode, some process either triggered by the vscode testing extension or conda (or both?!?!) modifies the PATH envvar so that the error occurs.

When I run `pytest .`in the terminal, the test runs fine.
When I run "Debug Test" the test runs fine.

Anybody any clue??

Setup: vscode 1.65, conda 4.9.2, python 3.8

*I'll try to provide an MVE once I find out how to reproduce it...*

Comment: Since it is trying to call the specific binary already, I don't think it is a PATH issue. Have you tried symlinking to the existing binary?

Comment: What's the `.profile` file?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I'm not sure what you mean. Where should I symlink the binary to?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT it's the config file for login shells. It executes bashrc and adds some paths to PATH.

Comment: @Robert Sorry for that, `.profile` was the macos related, I am using windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you add this to your settings.json file?

"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
"PYTHONPATH": "{the path of pg_ctl folder}"
},

When terminal settings are used, PYTHONPATH can affect any tools that are run within the terminal.

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) for more details.

Comment: Hm, ok it is odd, but it works! Thanks a lot. But I really don't get why I would need this path in my pythonpath...

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your upvote, if it's helpful, could you accept it? then other people who have a similar problem can find it easily.